# USB barcode scanner not work in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: usb, ubuntu-10.10, barcode-scanner

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 in my PC. After that I try to plug in USB barcode scanner, but after I have scanned some barcode, the data does not show.

Why its happen? I use Scan Logic SL-1000-LR barcode scanner.
could you give some advice?

---

I have tried `dmesg | grep usb` and got :

```
    [    1.573751] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.573751] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.573751] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    2.360026] usb 2-1: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
[    2.764025] usb 2-2: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
[    2.966136] usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
[    2.979023] input: OM as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input2
[    2.979169] generic-usb 0003:04F3:0232.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [OM] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
[    3.009021] input: HID 04d9:1203 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input3
[    3.009130] generic-usb 0003:04D9:1203.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [HID 04d9:1203] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-2/input0
[    3.070607] input: HID 04d9:1203 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/input/input4
[    3.070726] generic-usb 0003:04D9:1203.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [HID 04d9:1203] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-2/input1
[    3.070752] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.070755] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   16.840996] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
```

but I don't know what should I do after this.

Comment: I assume Scan Logic SL-1000-LR is the device (please tell me if I'm wrong), what kind of software do you use?

Comment: ya.its kind of barcode scanner device.what software do you mean?

Comment: You need some kind of software to use devices like barcode scanners, don't you? What program did you use to get the data before you installed ubuntu? Maybe this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BarcodeReaders is helpful for you.

Comment: i'm not use different program.but use different input device. 1st use keyboard type manually, and now i try to use barcode scanner.

Comment: I think you will need some kind of software to get the data from your barcode scanner.

Comment: did you mean barcode scanner driver or what?

Comment: @Michael K: Most barcode scanners operate as a "keyboard wedge" - the older ones used to have PS/2 connectors and were wired between the normal keyboard and the PC's keyboard port. Newer ones act as USB keyboard devices - so any PC and any modern O/S should recognise it as a keyboard device. You shouldn't need extra drivers so far as I know.

Comment: @Red: so, why the scanner couldn't show data after scan barcode?

Comment: Actually I was thinking about drivers, but I did not know that barcode scanners are recognized as keyboard, thanks for this information.

Comment: @klox - does your scanner work correctly on a Windows PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For USB Barcode Scanner i get no answer. I still can't work with that in ubuntu 10.10. I have try like RedGrittyBrick said, but it still same.

After that i try to Serial Barcode scanner, and i got the same problem. But i try to find the answer in google. Some sites told me that some app. in Ubuntu 10.10 not work properly. So, it needs to download some software from Ubuntu Software Centre.

Like Xoscope, we need to install `alsa-oss`. And for this case i choose to use serial barcode scanner, then i install `Softwedge`. After that i type some commands:

```
softwedge -c /dev/ttywhatever
```

After i use this, i can scan the barcode normally.

Answer (score 0):

The only descriptive information Google can find on the Scanlogic LS1000 is at an Indonesian [website](http://idscanlogic.com/) and they don't have any support pages for the product (only the usual marketing specification). The lack of support information doesn't give me much confidence in the product.

I don't know whether Ubuntu 10.10 supports the hot-plugging of keyboards so I would try powering the computer off and on again with the scanner connected.

It may be that the scanner doesn't implement the USB HID standards sufficiently fully for Ubuntu but does it well enough for Windows to recognise it. I am just speculating. In this case I would try a different USB barcode scanner - preferably one from a well-known manufacturer. This might help identify if the problem is with the PC, Ubuntu or the SL1000.

The output from `dmesg | grep usb` should be useful, it looks like it might have detected the USB scanner as a keyboard device `on usb-0000:00:1d.0-2/input1`. To be sure I'd disconnect it, reboot and compare the output of `dmesg | grep usb` with and without the scanner connected.

In theory I'd expect messages to be logged whenever you connect or disconnect a USB device - but I haven't tested this.

---

The [Opticon OPI2002](http://www.opticon.com/OPI2002.aspx) USB version supports either Human Interface Device (HID) or Virtual Com Port (VCP) profiles. To be recognised as a keyboard, it would have to be switched to HID mode. As with many scanners you configure it by scanning special bar-codes from a "menubook" supplement to the user guide. I would start by scanning the "reset to factory default" barcode. On page U6 is a barcode for "USB-HID" - scan that. Make sure power is connected and that you can see the red beam when you pull the trigger.

Comment: i have tried to unplug then reboot, after that i call `dmesg | grep usb` again. But the result is still same. Nothing changed. I have tried with another barcode scanner, use `Opticon OPI-2002` but it have same problem too.Any suggestion for this case?

Comment: oh..my barcode scanner can't work in windows too.why? but last time either in ubuntu 10.04 or windows xp it works.

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover the Opticon OPI2002 - at least Opticon provide a decent level of support - the manual and menubook are available as PDF downloads.