# Barcode scanner is not showing result

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-10.10, barcode-scanner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [USB barcode scanner not work in Ubuntu 10.10](https://superuser.com/questions/246456/usb-barcode-scanner-not-work-in-ubuntu-10-10)

I have a strange problem, my barcode scanner has stopped decoding barcodes.

I can hear a beep sound and the red light, but the resulting data is not shown. I have tried in both Ubuntu and Windows, but the problem is the same in both.

Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Did you change something? In some barcode scanners you can change settings by scanning special barcodes.

Comment: Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/246456/usb-barcode-scanner-not-work-in-ubuntu-10-10

Comment: @Red well spotted. As this is a direct duplicate by the same user, I'm closing it down. @Red (again), next time you spot this sort of incident please feel free to flag it so a ♦ can come along ASAP to sort it out. Thanks!